Lucene: Adding date filter combined with query across multiple text values, causes results with 0.0 match score
I am attempting to combine date filtering and querying across multiple text fields in Lucene.
For example, I want to query on title and content of the document and only include documents that have updated field in a particular date range.
The weird behavior that I am running into is when I add the date filter, I get documents included in the results that match the date filter but do not match the query string.
There are documents with literal 0.0 match score that come back.
Am I missing something in the query construction? Or is this the accepted behavior and I should just filter out the 0.0 score documents from results?
Below is the included code example with output:
Code
Using lucene 7.3.0 code, with Kotlin code example:
package lookup.lucene

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field
import org.apache.lucene.document.LongPoint
import org.apache.lucene.document.TextField
import org.apache.lucene.index.*
import org.apache.lucene.search.*
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory
import org.apache.lucene.store.RAMDirectory
import java.io.IOException
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*

object DateFilterTroubleshootingSandbox {
    private val indexDirectory: Directory = RAMDirectory()
    private val analyzer = StandardAnalyzer()
    val dateFormatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US)

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    @JvmStatic
    fun main(args: Array<String>) {
        setupIndex()
        // "ergonomic keyboard"
        performSearchWithDateFilter("ergonomic")
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun setupIndex() {
        val config = IndexWriterConfig(analyzer)
        val writer = IndexWriter(indexDirectory, config)

        addDoc(
            writer,
            "ergonomic keyboard Review (title and content match)",
            "Review of the latest ergonomic keyboard",
            dateFormatter.parse("2024-04-02").time
        )
        addDoc(
            writer,
            "Cycling Updates (completely unrelated)",
            "Best bicycles of 2024",
            dateFormatter.parse("2024-04-10").time
        )
        addDoc(
            writer,
            "Office Comfort (on word in content matches)",
            "Review of ergonomic chairs",
            dateFormatter.parse("2024-04-15").time
        )

        writer.close()
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun addDoc(
        writer: IndexWriter,
        title: String,
        content: String,
        updatedMillis: Long,
    ) {
        val doc = Document()
        doc.add(TextField("title", title, Field.Store.YES))
        doc.add(TextField("content", content, Field.Store.YES))

        doc.add(LongPoint("updatedMillis", updatedMillis))
        writer.addDocument(doc)
    }

    @Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun performSearchWithDateFilter(queryString: String) {
        println("performSearchWithDateFilter: $queryString")
        val reader: IndexReader = DirectoryReader.open(indexDirectory)
        val searcher = IndexSearcher(reader)
        val query = buildQuery(queryString, "2024-04-09", "2024-04-22")
        val docs = searcher.search(query, 10)
        printDocs(searcher, docs)
        reader.close()
    }

    private fun buildQuery(queryString: String, fromDate: String, toDate: String): Query {
        val booleanQuery = BooleanQuery.Builder()

        arrayOf("title", "content")
            .forEach { field ->
                booleanQuery.add(
                    BoostQuery(TermQuery(Term(field, queryString)), 1.1f), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD
                )
            }

        val fromMillis = dateFormatter.parse(fromDate).time
        val toMillis = dateFormatter.parse(toDate).time
        val dateRangeQuery = LongPoint.newRangeQuery("updatedMillis", fromMillis, toMillis)
        booleanQuery.add(dateRangeQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.FILTER)

        return booleanQuery.build()
    }

    private fun printDocs(searcher: IndexSearcher, docs: TopDocs) {
        docs.scoreDocs.forEach { scoreDoc ->
            val docId = scoreDoc.doc
            val doc = searcher.doc(docId)
            val title = doc.get("title")
            val content = doc.get("content")
            println("Doc ID: $docId, Score: ${scoreDoc.score}, Title='$title', Content='$content'")
        }
    }
}

Output
performSearchWithDateFilter: ergonomic
Doc ID: 2, Score: 0.5390563, Title='Office Comfort (on word in content matches)', Content='Review of ergonomic chairs'
Doc ID: 1, Score: 0.0, Title='Cycling Updates (completely unrelated)', Content='Best bicycles of 2024'


I am going to use Java, not Kotlin, because if I try to use Kotlin, I will probably make a mess of the code.

The results you are seeing relate to how the BooleanClause.Occur.FILTER operator works. As described here:

FILTER — Use this operator when a clause is required to occur in the result set but should not contribute to the score. Every document in the result set will match all such clauses.

See also here, where it is described as being:

Like MUST except that these clauses do not participate in scoring.

The code in the question builds the three clauses of your boolean query so that it effectively states:
Title may contain 'ergonomic' and content may contain 'ergonomic' and date range must be between x and y.
So, the result is that you do, in fact, get a score for that unexpected Doc ID 1 - because it matches the FILTER clause - and that score is 0.0.

Another approach to understanding the behavior is to look at one possible fix.
In this fix (apologies for Java not Kotlin), I re-write the buildQuery() method as follows:
private static Query buildQuery(String queryString, String fromDate, String toDate) throws ParseException {
    var termQuery = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
    Arrays.asList("title", "content").forEach(field -> {
        termQuery.add(
                new BoostQuery(new TermQuery(new Term(field, queryString)), 1.1f),
                BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
    });

    var fromMillis = dateFormatter.parse(fromDate).getTime();
    var toMillis = dateFormatter.parse(toDate).getTime();
    var dateRangeQuery = LongPoint.newRangeQuery("updatedMillis", fromMillis, toMillis);
    var datesQuery = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
    datesQuery.add(dateRangeQuery, BooleanClause.Occur.FILTER);
    
    var finalQuery = new BooleanQuery.Builder();
    finalQuery.add(termQuery.build(), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);
    finalQuery.add(datesQuery.build(), BooleanClause.Occur.MUST);

    return finalQuery.build();
}

Here I have introduced one additional BooleanQuery which allows me to effectively nest the two SHOULD keyword queries in parentheses - by placing them in a separate BooleanQuery object. Then I place the FILTER term into a "final" BooleanQuery object and give that a MUST operator.
Now, with this code, the output you get is as follows:
performSearchWithDateFilter: ergonomic
Doc ID: 2 Score: 0.5390563 Title='Office Comfort (on word in content matches) Content='Review of ergonomic chairs'

Just the one hit you were expecting.

Finally, another way to compare the two approaches is to print out the textual representation of the query which gets executed:
System.out.println(query.toString());

The original query:
(title:ergonomic)^1.1 (content:ergonomic)^1.1 #updatedMillis:[1712646000000 TO 1713769200000]

The updated query:
+((title:ergonomic)^1.1 (content:ergonomic)^1.1) +(#updatedMillis:[1712646000000 TO 1713769200000])

Note how the parentheses around the first two search terms mean that you MUST (the +) find the search term in either title or content (or both) - and then you MUST also match the date range (but that will not affect the overall matching score).

Or, as you note, you could keep your code and just filter the results to remove anything with a score of zero.
Probably the least intuitive part of all of this is the fact that you get the zero-scored document returned to you, using the original code. This is how Lucene works when using FILTER. Everything which matches the filter is given a score (of 0.0). Everything with a score is returned - even if there is no additional scoring information provided by any of the other clauses (e.g. your keyword clauses).
(Lucene "booleans" are not exactly like the behavior of booleans you may be used to seeing elsewhere! But that should not be entirely surprising since Lucene is first and foremost trying to rank by relevance, and not simply include/reject. Hence it uses SHOULD and MUST as its operators. But in other places it also tries to map these to more familiar boolean operators such as AND, OR, NOT.)
